# How to disable pop-out in pdf when embedded to my blog

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, blogspot

My problem is I want to disable the pop-out button of my embedded pdf on Blogspot. I uploaded it in my google drive and embedded it. This https://i.stack.imgur.com/toVnN.png

I can embed it fine and it's working but I wanna know if it's possible to disable that pop-up button? I've seen similar questions here but I can't really understand it much what people meant by webview or something. Since I'm using a PC.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.